# How to try a tactic in Ltac, but continue if it fails

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a proof which concludes in two cases which look like this:

```
+ rewrite H. apply lemma1.
+ apply lemma1.
```

While this is relatively simple I would like to combine this into a single tactic. What I want to do in English is, "try to rewrite and if that fails, do nothing and try to apply `lemma1`.

So a related question is "What is the tactic that does nothing?"

Here is one of my attempts:

```
try (rewrite H || nil); apply lemma1.
```

I don't know know how to figure out what the "empty tactic" in Ltac is, nor how to find out its name.

Here is another, where I "distributed out" `lemma1`.

```
do 2 try (rewrite H; apply lemma1 || apply lemma1).
```

which also didn't prove the second case.

Comment: The empty tactic is "idtac"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not need a "do nothing" tactic in this case because when tactic given to the `try` fails `try` does nothing. If I see you right you want just `try rewrite H; apply lemma1.` and that is. So, it will try to rewrite H and in success case it will apply lemma1. Otherwise, when rewrite fails, it will just apply lemma1. So, it applies lemma1 in any case.

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution which I had overcomplicated. It did not work in my actual proof because in the second bullet, one needed _not_ to rewrite.